# UILabel does not appear on SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uilabel, skscene, skview

I am trying to create a `label` on my `SKScene` but it is not appearing. I don't know what is wrong. The code seems perfectly fine:

```
class end: SKScene {

    var label = UILabel()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(59.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(89.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(152.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))

         label.text = "Game Over!"
         label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
         label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width/3, height: 30))
         label.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.width/7)
         label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         self.view?.addSubview(label)      
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know it is not appearing?  first, what is .center?  That is not a normal UILabel property from what I can tell

Comment: n/m  center is a member of UIVIew,  so the issue now is what are the coordinates.  I am going to assume you are using auto layout,  and at the time that didMoveToView is called,  you are working in default coordinates, then autolayout takes over moving the view to outside of some forseeable scope perhaps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have set `textColor` and `backgroundColor` both `whiteColor()`, change any one will show your text properly.

**Edit:**

I think you want to add the label inside `view` that you are passing as a parameter than use `view.addSubview(label)` instead of `self.view?.addSubview(label)`.

Comment: i changed the background to black but it's still not showing. even if i hadn't changed, the label of white color should have shown on the screen but it doesn't show at all

Comment: @NDoc self.view is populated at the time of didMoveToView is called

Answer (score 1):

In `Sprite-kit` you should use [SKLabelNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/) in your scene instead of add a `UIKit` label directly to your view because this could cause bad performance to your game.

I make an example:

```
let titleLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"HelveticaNeue-Bold")
titleLabel.text = String("Game Over!")
titleLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
titleLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2.0, y: size.height/2)
self.addChild(titleLabel)
```

You can find `SKLabelNode` also in the Sprite-kit Xcode demo project "hello, world":

[image]

Comment: this really helped!! Thank YOU SO MUCH!